# After getting user inputs the last printf() is not printing at all

Tags: c

Struggling on my homework assignment.

After I give inputs it stops rather than doing the random array and last print if anyone can help I would appreciate it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char name, color;
    int age;
    int *poer = &age;
    char *p = &name;
    char *ptr = &color;

    printf("What is your name?\n");
    scanf(" %s", &name);
    printf("How old are you??\n");
    scanf(" %d", &age);
    printf("What is your favorite color?\n");
    scanf(" %s", &color);

    char *story[5] = {"old volkswagen beetle", "singlet", "quater", "left sock",
                      "blackberry bold ninek"};
    srand(time(0));

    printf("My pal right here %s is %d years old I feel like we have been coding"
        " together for a hundred years now I always wonder where the time has gone"
        " One thing I have wanted to know is why they love "
        "their %s %s so much I guess I might never know\n",
        name, age, color, story[rand() % 5]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%s` requires a `char` *buffer* to store the data it receives, the size of which *must* be at least the length of the string *and* the terminating nullchar. Unless it somehow receives an empty string, a single-char will *never* be enough space, yet that's what you're using. In so doing, you're code invokes *undefined behavior*. Whatever resource you're using to teach you `scanf` reaping of `%s` formatted data, review it again, or find another resource. That you're later passing `char` values to printf format `%s` expecting `const char*` just pours salt on the open wound.

Comment: @WhozCraig `%s` can never receive an empty string.

Comment: Hint: `char name[MAX_STR]` where you `#define MAX_STR 255` or something like that.

Comment: You should have gotten a warning when compiling `printf()`, since the argument corresponding to `%s` needs to be `char *`, but you provided `char`.

Comment: Excellent documentation of the `scanf` family, including examples of multiple data types, behavior and requirements of all format strings, etc, [can be found here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Answer (score 1):

**Plenty of errors can be caught by enabling the compiler warnings.**

Here is the list of all problems with their proper solutions:

1. For this line:

   ```
   srand(time(0));
   ```

   You need to include the `time.h` library, otherwise, you will get an implicit definition of `time()` error message. Passing `NULL` to `time()` is a good practice.
2. As people figured out:

   ```
   char name, color;
   ```

   A single char-type cannot hold more than a single ASCII character. Thus, you need to formulate a sequence of characters, called character array. In C99, variable-length arrays are supported. Still, using a macro constant for defining string lengths during compile-time makes the code good. Replace it:

   ```
   #define MAX_LENGTH 128 // Prefer your length
   ...
   char name[MAX_LENGTH], color[MAX_LENGTH];
   ```
3. In the similar lines:

   ```
   printf("What is your name?\n");
   scanf(" %s", &name);
   ```

   `scanf()` function stops reading further input after whitespace. For example, if you input: `John Doe`, the `name` will only store `John`, `Doe` becomes truncated. Also, never put an ampersand sign for a char-array in `scanf()`.

   `fgets()` is considered safer than this, since it accepts a limited number of characters defined in its second argument. Replace the `scanf()`:

   ```
   //     ...    , sizeof name, ... --- is also applicable here
   if (fgets(name, MAX_LENGTH, stdin) == NULL) {
       // Do something when input's invalid
   }
   // Input is okay
   ```

   **Note:** The `fgets()` leaves a trailing newline character as soon as it stops receiving user input. To discard this, use this after its usage:

   ```
   name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = 0;
   ```

After applying all these changes, you will not get any further problems.

Answer (score 0):

the following code will be fine

```c
       char name[256];
        char color[256];
        int age;

        printf("What is your name?\n");
        scanf(" %s", name);
        printf("How old are you??\n");
        scanf(" %d", &age);
        printf("What is your favorite color?\n");
        scanf(" %s", color);
```

in your code, a char was casted to char* the variable will hold data larger than it could. the the stack was ruined

Answer (score 0):

You used char for string which is wrong. You need a char array to store the strings.

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#define STR_MAX 300

int main()
{
    char name[STR_MAX];
    char color[STR_MAX];
    int age;
        
    printf("What is your name?\n");
    scanf(" %s", name);
    printf("How old are you??\n");
    scanf(" %d", &age);
    printf("What is your favorite color?\n");
    scanf(" %s", color);

    char *story[5] = {"old volkswagen beetle","singlet","quater","left sock","blackberry bold ninek"};
    srand(time(0));

    printf("My pal right here %s is %d years old I feel like we have been coding together for a hundred years now I always wonder where the time has gone One thing I have wanted to know is why they love their %s %s so much I guess I might never know\n",name, age, color, story[rand()%5]);

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: [**Please do not upload images of text (code/input/output/errors, or otherwise) on Stack Overflow**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please [edit] your answer, pasting all text into the answer with [correct formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

your program terminated abnormally because stack was ruined.

```
char name;  //has only 1 byte space
char color; //has only 1 byte space
```

but these two variables was used to hold data larger than they can. then data was written to some place else which will cause the stack overflow.

code like this will be ok

```
char name[256];
char color[256];
```